# Hibernate auto update column not changed by code

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

while application 1  get entity by id and process it, application 2  update column A of entity same id that application 1 was processing and save to database. After that, application 1 update and override column A , although application 1 dont change cloumn A and entity is marked by dynamicUpdate. why ? and how make hibernate update only field is changed by setter.

Comment: Your should use `optimistic` or `pessimistic` [locking](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking).

Comment: i cant use lock because multiple application update some a part of table  in the same time.

Comment: Locking refers to actions taken to prevent data from changing between the time it is read and the time is used. Without locking you can obtain unpredictable results.

Comment: I know but i want to multiple application can update diferent  part of table in the same time, its mean application a update column a and dont impact column B if not change in application a.

Comment: Could you please provide code of your entity. What hibernate version do you use? Could you also provide your hibernate config.